# EEG signal windowing and framing in python

Tags: signal-analysis, python, eeg

I would like to do EEG signal(using 1 channel) Windowing and Framing.

Actually I am doing my thesis and following a research paper.In this paper they explained

*"Windowing consists of dividing entire EEG signals into a number of windows of specific time intervals which is 1 min selected. Framing consists of the dividing selected window into a number of frames of the specified time interval. Frames can be overlapping and non-overlapping. Typically it is selected as 1sec."*

By following this paper I have done my implementation below:

```
data,times = Be_band[:] 
print('data shape ==>row,colm',data.shape)  #data shape ==>row,colm (1, 2561)
print('time shape ==>row,colm',times.shape) #time shape ==>row,colm (2561,)
print('data len ==>',len(data))              #data len ==> 1
fs=128  #sampling frequency
```

Then I perform the windowing and framing task as follows:

```
window_hop_length= 0.01 #10ms 
overlap=int(fs*window_hop_length)
print(overlap,'Overlap') # got  1
window_size=0.60 #1min in window size,
framesize=int(window_size*fs)
length= len(data)
number_of_frames=int(length/overlap)
frames=np.ndarray((number_of_frames,framesize))

print(framesize,'frame size')
print("number_of_frames=",number_of_frames)
print( frames)
```

And I got the result of my implementation:

```
1 Overlap
76 frame size
number_of_frames= 1
```

The number of frames make me confused,because it is one.

Can any one help me how can I implement this correctly in Python?

For coding I used [this](https://deerishi.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/signal-processing-using-python-part-1/) as a reference.

Comment: You have only 128 samples per second, so 0.01ms corresponds to hardly 1 sample. That is why Overlap = 1. Make it bigger like 5 samples. (0.04ms hop length)

Comment: When I changed the 'length =(data.size)' then it gives the 'number of frame =213'.If i change hope length like 0.04ms with out changing 'length =len(data) ' it does change number of frame.